# iMacro cannot increase the speed of script?

Tags: imacros

I am using iMacro to perform an automated form-test which I want to increase the speed of. I have looked at [this](http://wiki.imacros.net/!REPLAYSPEED) solution at iMacros wiki-page which tells me to insert `SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST` in the beginning. This does not work - the test does not execute that row when I look at the GUI of iMacro but all the other rows are executed.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with timeout step and errorignore to yes like:

```
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
```

Or it's with javascript (*.js) with iMacros for Firefox?
Then deselect "Show Javascript during replay" under Manage => Settings => General => Javascript scripting settings.

Answer (score 2):

By Default the Replay speed is set as 'Fast' only. If you want you can change it from options or settings http://screencast.com/t/TW6nK6v7YZE . Also this option is (either you mention it in the script or select the option), it's for the entire script, not specific to the particular row. If a particular row is not executed, there might be some issue in that row which you need to fix it.

If you share the script, it might be helpful for better understanding of the problem